# How can I create delegates to a property of unknown type?

Tags: vb.net

I'm using reflection to access an object's properties by name, to call the get method. This is a relatively slow operation over thousands of iterations, even when I cache the PropertyInfo for each property. I'm trying to come up with something faster using delegates, but VB.Net won't allow me to call CreateDelegate on an object without knowing the return type of the property at compile time. How can I do this?

- I access properties via their (string) name
- The return type of the property is unknown at compile time
- I'm trying to create a delegate to quickly access one or more properties on thousands of instances of an object

Edit: Code follows

testC is an example object which contains the properties I'm acessing by name. del is the delegate I want to use to call the property on an instance of testC.

```
Public Class testC
        Public Property prop1 As String
        Public Property prop2 As Double
        Public Property prop3 As Integer
        Public Property prop4 As String
        Public Property prop5 As String
        Public Property prop6 As String
End Class

Public Delegate Function del() As Object
```

The first time I access each property, I use reflection to get the property from it's name, and attempt to build a delegate to quickly access it on other instances of the object in the future.

```
Dim pi As Reflection.PropertyInfo = obj.GetType().GetProperty(propName)
Dim myDelegate As Object = System.Delegate.CreateDelegate(GetType(del), pi.GetGetMethod())
```

Calling CreateDelegate throws this exception:

> System.ArgumentException: Cannot bind to the target method because its
>   signature or security transparency is not compatible with that of the
>   delegate type.

Comment: I'm not sure what benefit Delegates would provide.  Wouldn't the delegate still need to use reflection to get the PropertyInfo and the objects underlying value?

Comment: The first time it accesses the property it will, but the delegate will access the same property on a large number of instances of the object

Comment: Can you use a generic return type (like Object)?

Comment: Also, it would be helpful to know where your objects are coming from.  Are we to assume that you don't have access to a .GetType method?

Comment: Couldn't get it to work using a delegate that returns object.
No reason why I wouldn't have a GetType method for the properties

Comment: I've added code to the original post

Comment: The posted code cannot work because a *boxing conversion* is required to go from, say, a Double to an Object.  Normally automatically emitted by the compiler but no longer automatic now.  Reflection.Emit is the usual weapon to make this fast.  The System.Dynamic namespace qualifies too.

Comment: Is the problem that the delegate has return type object and the properties return other types? I already tried using a delegate that returns string and it still wouldn't let me run CreateDelegate on the string property.